# Share SQL login amongst multiple SQL Server Database projects in VS17

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a single SQL Server with two databases which to update I use Visual studio SSDT projects.

Within my VS solution I have two SQL Database projects named Db_1 and Db_2.
Db_2 has numerous tables populated with data.
Inside of Db_1 I have created a view which selects data from Db_2.

The issue I am having within the solution is, how do I share the SQL Server login amongst both database projects so that the SQL Server login is mapped to more than one user.

I currently have the "CREATE LOGIN" (SQL Authentication) script in Db_1 project and Db_1 also has a reference to Db_2 to able to see the tables which the view uses.

When I add a reference from Db_2 to Db_1 in order to use the login to create the user which will give permission to select the table I get a circular reference.

Is it possible to share a SQL Server login amongst two sql database projects?
Or should I be looking at this in a different way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you should not use SQL Server logins, you should use windows logins. Then you don't have to deploy them (or more importantly: put clear text passwords in your deployment and your config). However there are many things to consider which are well beyond the scope of this question, primarily, what kind of infrastructure are you deploying to?

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you use one server and 2 databases on it or you use 2 different servers. Please, precise it

Comment: I have updated the description @sepupic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm not sure if this is the best way of achieving the solution but as per above I have two projects. I have created a third project called common and then in the other two projects referenced the common project and moved the server logins in to there. Hope this helps. Would still be interested to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: You need to reference it as "the same database" (you have that option when you referencing database). In that case these logins when you publish from your Db_1 or Db_2 databases, you will not need to publish that database separately.